# Need a software that can monitor and log network traffic of installed applications

Tags: network, windows, monitoring, software

I need to monitor and log network activities of a specific software installed on my system.

I know there are lots of network monitoring software out there, even system explorer has one built in.

I need a Windows-based application I can run in the background, it should collect the network traffic of a process software or a set of processes.

Comment: This sounds like it'd quickly fill up your disk. What's your end goal? Seems like something an IDS / IPS might be better for.

Answer (score 6):

[Microsoft Network Mintor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or NetMon for short allows you to monitor/log/analyze network traffic.

After you start capturing, you can specify a process and monitor the network activity of that process.

[image: NetMon_Processes]

If you just want to know the IP addresses, ports, and protocols used by the process, you can try something like this in the command prompt

```
netstat -ano | findstr PID
```

You can get the PID either from your Windows Task Manager, or with the following command

```
tasklist | findstr /i PROCESS_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Nagios should be able to do the job for you (although like you said there are plenty to choose from).

You have an agent running in the background collecting data, then you can view reports and be notified when certain things happen (like services going down etc).

http://www.nagios.org/about/features

> Comprehensive Monitoring
>
> Capabilities to monitor applications, services, operating systems,
>   network protocols, system metrics and infrastructure components with a
>   single tool Powerful script APIs allow easy monitoring of in-house and
>   custom applications, services, and systems

Nagios works for windows, although I've only tried it on linux so far. Here is information about nagios for windows http://www.nagios.com/solutions/windows-service-monitoring

There are a number of plugins and reports available, this will give you a quick look at what you can expect http://www.nagios.com/products/nagiosxi/screenshots

Another bit of software to consider is OPSVIEW which takes advantage of nagios core but extends and adds other features http://www.opsview.com/technology/guides-help/monitoring-examples/opsview-nagios-users

Comment: Nagios doesn't seem like it solves the problem. It seems that OP wants to monitor the traffic itself, rather than system state.

Comment: There are plugins for nagios, and opsview is built off nagois core so I believe this is possible, I'm just not sure how easy it is.

OPSVIEW has a forum which might be helpful, e.g ...

http://www.opsview.com/forum/opsview-community-edition/monitoring-microsoft-windows-servers/windows-nic-traffic

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [Net Orbit](http://www.net-orbit.com/LAN-monitoring-software.html) monitoring software once. It records and monitors all the activities of employee PC. It can also provides you live monitoring of the employee PC. So it will helps you in detecting all the problems at workplace.